# How to get return code from GAMS Python API run

Tags: python, gams-math

Is there a way to get the return code from running a GamsJob in the GAMS Python API? Meaning, after I do job.run(), is the return code from this execution stored somewhere I can access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`job.run()` will throw an exception with the return code stored in the attribute `.rc` if the return code is non-zero. Therefore:

```
try:
    job.run()
except GamsExceptionExecution as e:
    print(e.rc)  # This is a non-zero return code
```

Answer (score 1):

The return code should be in the same folder as the run file.

For instance, with the **transport1.py** example detailed here https://gams.com/latest/docs/apis/examples_python/index.html, you can find the .lst file as follows:

- t1._file_name gives you a "PATH\transport.gms" (where transport.gms is the file defining the model to run)
- t1._job_name gives you the job name
- from there: PATH\t1._job_name.lst is the lst file, as follows:

  ```
  os.path.dirname(t1._file_name)+"\\"+t1._job_name+".lst"
  ```